# Saving pointers of struct c

Tags: c, struct

I am loading some data into struct.

```
struct test {
    char x[101];
    char y[101];       
    int z;
};
```

Then I create memory for structs

```
struct test * data;
data = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct test));
```

And fill data like this

```
data[0].z = 123;
```

This works alright. But I wanna sort these structs. Like sort them depending on z attribute.

My idea was to create a new array and fill it with pointers which will point to the right struct.

Can somebody tell me how or if there is better way?

Thanks

Comment: The way you mentioned, creating a new array of pointers, is the best way, that is, doesn't require sorting the actual data.

Comment: You can also use `qsort` to sort `data`.

Comment: Yeah @FiddlingBits but I dont know how to do it

Comment: @user2976389 You can do what R Sahu suggested and use `qsort` to sort the array of pointers.  The array of data will remain unsorted.

Comment: I need to sort it with custom algorythm, z attribute was just example.

Comment: your structs are relatively large, so you'll probably want to use a struct test ** for sorting, to avoid large memory copies.

Comment: `qsort` with a suitable callback should do the trick.

Comment: @user2976389 You can use `qsort` to sort by any attribute you choose by defining a sorting function for it.  If you need to define a custom sorting algorithm, then you will need to pass the address of the array of pointers to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using qsort, the general sorting algorithm provided in the standard library for sorting sequences of user-defined data. With a goal of doing the following:

- the source data must remain un-touched.
- the "sorted" access must be provided via a list of pointers to the untouched data from above

this is one way to do that using the `qsort()` standard library function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct test {
    char x[101];
    char y[101];
    int z;
};

int cmp_test_ptrs(const void* arg1, const void* arg2)
{
    struct test const * lhs = *(struct test const * const*)arg1;
    struct test const * rhs = *(struct test const * const*)arg2;
    return (lhs->z < rhs->z) ? -1 : (rhs->z < lhs->z);
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    // populate data array.
    struct test * data = malloc(10 * sizeof(*data));
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        data[i].z = rand() % 20;
        printf("%d ", data[i].z);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // allocate a pointer array to use as a sort-bed, copying each
    //  structure address into this pointer array afterward
    struct test **ptrs = malloc(10 * sizeof(*ptrs));
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ptrs[i] = data+i;

    // sort the pointer bed using our comparator
    qsort(ptrs, 10, sizeof(*ptrs), cmp_test_ptrs);

    // ptrs now has sorted pointers. Note the dereference for access
    //  to the actual data, which remains where it originally was.
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%d ", ptrs[i]->z);
    printf("\n");

    free(ptrs);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
11 7 6 17 8 8 11 4 7 5 
4 5 6 7 7 8 8 11 11 17
```

Important to note is the original structure array remained untouched. We sorted a sequence of *pointers*, not the actual structures themselves, and used what those pointers *pointed-to* as the criteria for the sort.

Anyway, I hope it helps. Study the comparator and the setup for `qsort()` carefully. They're important. You can read more about [`qsort()` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your goal. If you are trying to figure out what would be most programmer efficient, then creating an ordering functor based on the z attribute of your struct, and sorting the list directly, is easiest.

However, if you are concerned with program efficiency, then it will be faster to sort pointers, as suggested by Fiddling Bits. However, you must keep in mind that this will give you a sorted list of pointers- your data array will still be in the same order.

For instance, if `datapoints` is your array of pointers, and you wanted to sort by the z value, you could define the comparison

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ( (*(test *)a).z -(*(test *)b).z );
}
```

And then call

```
qsort( datapoints, 10, sizeof(test), compare);
```

Full documentation for qsort can be found [here:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)

Comment: @user2976389 Start working on it, post a new question if you get stuck somewhere. If you want someone to write code for you, you are on the wrong website.

Comment: @RedAlert Slow down, I didnt ask for full sorting code, I just asked how can I do pointer array

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just sort them in the same array and probably save some memory (4 bytes for a pointer of any type) :P
Doesn't really matter though, pointers'll work fine I guess.
But I think that in some cases pointers will be more useful as if you would sort it in the array you'll need a temporary struct defined to contain structs when you're sorting and if you're struct is big than you'll actually take a lot more memory than 4 bytes.
+Also remember that when defining a pointer to a struct - access it with `->` operator.
Usage: `STRUCT_POINTER_NAME->VARIABLE`